# Issues with retrieving list of all Azure AD applications using Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to get a list of all applications in my Azure AD.  I use the following query: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications?&$select=displayName  it only returns the applications that my company owns, but not all applications (i.e. applications that my company uses).  How to get a list of all apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application objects represent the global registration for applications your organization develops.

When using an application developed by another organization (multi-tenant applications), a local Service Principal object is created in your tenant  representing that application.

To get a list of all the applications your company uses, you should query for the list of Service Principals in your tenant.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincpials`

Comment: To be more precise, a service principal is created for *every* application, including the ones in the same directory :)